# detox jest tests are not running in parallel

Tags: ios, jestjs, detox

Detox Automation with Jest

Hi, I am running detox tests form the CLI with the below command. 
detox test -r  --maxWorkers 2 to achieve parallel execution.

Already one simulator started with name iphone 5s-Detox  and with the maxWorkers 2 or --workers 2, one more simulator is launching but the tests are executing in only one simulator. I want to execute tests in parallel to save the execution time.

**Can anyone share concept of detox jest parallel execution. Is this same as testNG or it's different.**

in Detox simulator tests are running fine, but new worker got app installed and freezes with out any action

not sure what is the use of this device.registry.state ???

Unable to understand the locking mechanism, as mentioned

> https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.ParallelTestExecution.md

Can any one help on this to understand better jets parallel execution.

Comment: Please share both your detox configuration (from `package.json`) and Detox' logs. Also, please be sure to run the command with `--workers` (`maxWorkers` is a Jest arg rather than Detox').